# which one: "so and such" or "Bla Bla Bla ..."?

Tags: expressions

friend has said **something**, that is, something which is not true. I want to talk about what my friend said, but I won't actually say those words. I know I can use a sentence with following form:

> My friend said **so and such**.
>
> My friend said **Bla Bla Bla.**

I want to know: Is using **so and such** better than **Bla Bla Bla ...**? Or is there a better expression would we use?

Comment: Have I got this right?  Your friend said something false or incorrect.  You want to refer to what they said with a non-specific phrase like *such and such* or *blah blah blah*.  You want to know what the most appropriate non-specific phrase is, given that what they said was false or incorrect.  Is that right?

Comment: @snailboat Yes, I did pose my question a little vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Blah, blah, blah](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blah-blah-blah)* is fairly appropriate here.

> My friend just blabbered on about how great his job was, blah, blah, blah.

Keep in mind that "blah, blah, blah" isn't reserved for referring to lies/falsehoods. For example, in the above sentence, we are not implying your friend's job isn't great, but rather that he kept talking about his job for too long.

*Yada, yada, yada* or *went on and on* might also mean something similar.

*So and such*, as far as I know, is not a idiomatic. The closest expression, *so-and-so*, usually refers to a person or a thing.

> We shouldn't repaint our fence just because so-and-so said it looks old!

Comment: I, too, have not seen _so and such_, but I have seen _such and so_ used in this context. _“How would I say in Japanese, ‘I solve the Dirac Equation’?” They said such-and-so."_ is attributed to Richard Feynman; during her confirmation hearing, US Supreme Court Justice Ruth Ginsburg said, _"One of your colleagues just said to me, well, in the case of United States v. Jackson (1987), you said such-and-so._. Yet another way to say it might be [_this and that_](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/this+and+that).